# Flutter user authentication using bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, bloc

I am new to flutter and flutter Bloc state management and architecture.

I working on a OTP authentication application.

The main idea is to take Phone number from the user and give two option of OTP verification - phone and whatsapp.

Once OTP send from the backend Nodejs application. Assume Node API /sendOtp and /verifyOtp

Ask for the OTP from the user and authenticate.

Once they authenticated, use the user's data to other part of the application. And when app restart the entire user's data should be reload and used to part of application.

I just want to verify that I'm doing in the best way of authentication.

Here is my entire code - let me know if any small issue in the code I just want to make a best authentication and learn a lot from it:

## main.dart

```
void main() async {
  AuthBloc authBloc = AuthBloc();
  restoreUserData(authBloc);

  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => authBloc,
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // Global key in another file.
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: GlobalConstant.TITLE,
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> restoreUserData(AuthBloc authBloc) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? userString = prefs.getString(Keys.USER);

  if (userString != null) {
    User user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(userString));
    authBloc.add(UpdateUserData(user));
  }
}
```

## SplashScreen.dart

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => SplashScreenCubit(),
      child: BlocListener<SplashScreenCubit, SplashScreenState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state == SplashScreenState.authenticated) {
            NavigatorFunction.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context, const NavigatorBar());
          } else {
            NavigatorFunction.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context, const LoginScreen());
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold( 
          body: Center(
            child: Lottie.asset(
              GlobalConstant.SPLASH_SCREEN_LOTTIE_LINK,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## SplashScreenCubit.dart

```
enum SplashScreenState { start, authenticated, unauthenticated }

class SplashScreenCubit extends Cubit<SplashScreenState> {
  SplashScreenCubit() : super(SplashScreenState.start) {
    _timer();
  }
  Future<void> _timer() async {
    Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
      () async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        bool isAuthenticated = prefs.getBool(Keys.IS_AUTHENTICATED) ?? false;
        String? userString = prefs.getString(Keys.USER);

        if(userString != null){
          AuthBloc authBloc = AuthBloc();
          User user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(userString));
          authBloc.add(UpdateUserData(user));
        }

        if (isAuthenticated) {
          emit(SplashScreenState.authenticated);
        } else {
          emit(SplashScreenState.unauthenticated);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

## AuthEvent.dart

```
abstract class AuthEvent {}

class AuthOtpRequestEvent extends AuthEvent {
  final String phone;
  final bool isWhatsapp;
  AuthOtpRequestEvent(this.phone, this.isWhatsapp);
}

class AuthVerifyRequestEvent extends AuthEvent {
  final String phone;
  final String hash;
  final String otp;
  AuthVerifyRequestEvent(this.phone, this.hash, this.otp);
}

class UpdateUserData extends AuthEvent{
  final User user;
  UpdateUserData(this.user);
}
```

## AuthState.dart

```
abstract class AuthState {}

class AuthInitial extends AuthState {}

class AuthOtpLoading extends AuthState {
  final bool isWhatsapp;
  AuthOtpLoading(this.isWhatsapp);
}

class AuthOtpFailed extends AuthState {
  final String message;
  AuthOtpFailed(this.message);
}

class AuthOtpSuccess extends AuthState {
  final bool isWhatsapp;
  final SendResponseModel sendResponseModel;
  AuthOtpSuccess(this.sendResponseModel, this.isWhatsapp);
}

class AuthVerifyLoading extends AuthState {}

class AuthVerifySuccess extends AuthState {
  VerifyResponseModel verifyResponseModel;
  AuthVerifySuccess(this.verifyResponseModel);
}

class AuthVerifyFailed extends AuthState {
  final String message;
  AuthVerifyFailed(this.message);
}

class UserDataState extends AuthState{
  final User user;
  
  UserDataState(this.user);
}
```

## AuthBloc.dart

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc() : super(AuthInitial()) {
    on<AuthOtpRequestEvent>(_sendOtp);

    on<AuthVerifyRequestEvent>(_verifyOtp);

    on<UpdateUserData>(_updateUser);
  }

  FutureOr<void> _sendOtp(
      AuthOtpRequestEvent event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    try {
      final String phone = event.phone;
      final bool isWhatsapp = event.isWhatsapp;

      emit(AuthOtpLoading(isWhatsapp));

      if (phone.length != 10) {
        return emit(AuthOtpFailed(GlobalConstant.PHONE_ERROR_MESSAGE));
      }

      SendResponseModel response = await AuthRepo.sendOtp(phone, isWhatsapp); // Asume AuthRepo.sendOtp() usage AuthServices to request for send OTP to node application give the response or throw error

      emit(AuthOtpSuccess(response, isWhatsapp));
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is MessageException) {
        return emit(AuthOtpFailed(e.message));
      }
      return emit(AuthOtpFailed("Something Went Wrong!"));
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> _verifyOtp(
      AuthVerifyRequestEvent event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    try {
      final String otp = event.otp;
      final String phone = event.phone;
      final String hash = event.hash;

      if (otp.length != 4) {
        return emit(AuthVerifyFailed(
            "Please Enter your OTP recieved on phone number $phone"));
      }

      emit(AuthVerifyLoading());
      VerifyResponseModel response = await AuthRepo.verifyOtp(phone, hash, otp); // Asume AuthRepo.verifyOtp() request for verify OTP to node application 
      await APIUtilityFunction.updateSharePrefAuthDetails(response, false); // Save the Users Details and Tokens to sharepreference - false flag is for tokens and user's data, true for only token save.
      emit(AuthVerifySuccess(response));
      add(UpdateUserData(response.user));
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is MessageException) {
        return emit(AuthOtpFailed(e.message));
      }
      return emit(AuthOtpFailed("Something Went Wrong!"));
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> _updateUser(UpdateUserData event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) {
    emit(UserDataState(event.user));
  }
}
```

## sendResponseModel.dart

```
class SendResponseModel {
  String phone;
  String hash;

  SendResponseModel({
    required this.phone,
    required this.hash,
  });

  factory SendResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      SendResponseModel(
        phone: json["phone"],
        hash: json["hash"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "phone": phone,
        "hash": hash,
      };
}
```

## verifyResponseModel.dart

```
class VerifyResponseModel {
  User user;
  String accessToken;
  String refreshToken;
  bool auth;

  VerifyResponseModel({
    required this.user,
    required this.accessToken,
    required this.refreshToken,
    required this.auth,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'user': user.toJson(),
      'accessToken': accessToken,
      'refreshToken': refreshToken,
      'auth': auth,
    };
  }

  factory VerifyResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return VerifyResponseModel(
      user: User.fromJson(json['user'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      accessToken: json['accessToken'] as String,
      refreshToken: json['refreshToken'] as String,
      auth: json['auth'] as bool,
    );
  }
}
```

## UserModel.dart

```
class User {

  String? id;
  String? phone;
  String? fullName;
  
  User({
    this.id,
    this.phone,
    this.fullName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      '_id': id,
      'phone': phone,
      'fullName': fullName,
 
    };
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['_id'] as String?,
      phone: json['phone'] as String?,
      fullName: json['fullName'] as String?,
    );
  }
}
```

## AuthInterceptor.dart

```
class AuthenticationInterceptor extends InterceptorsWrapper {
  static const String _contentType = "application/json";

  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String accessToken =
        sharedPreferences.getString(Keys.ACCESS_TOKEN) ?? "";
    options.headers[Keys.ACCESS_TOKEN] = accessToken;
    options.contentType = _contentType;

    print("Request ${options.data}");

    handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(
      Response<dynamic> response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print('RESPONSE: ${response.data}');

    handler.next(response);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioException err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    try {
      if (err.response?.statusCode == 403 &&
          err.requestOptions.extra['isRetry'] == null) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final String refreshToken =
            sharedPreferences.getString(Keys.REFRESH_TOKEN) ?? "";

        Options options = Options();
        options.extra = {"isRetry": true};

        final response = await AuthServices.refreshToken(refreshToken, options); // AuthServices that i mentioned AuthBloc.dart

        if (response.auth) {
          await APIUtilityFunction.updateSharePrefAuthDetails(response, true);

          return handler
              .resolve(await AuthServices.afterRefresh(err.requestOptions));
        }
        throw Error();
      }
    } catch (er) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await sharedPreferences.clear();
      UtilityFunction.showScaffoldMessenger(navigatorKey.currentContext!,
          "Session Expire, Please login again!", Colors.blue);
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          navigatorKey.currentContext!, // navigatorKey - Global key in another file.
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoginScreen()),
          (route) => false);
    }
    handler.next(err);
  }
}
```

## LoginScreen.dart

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({super.key});
  final TextEditingController mobileController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthOtpSuccess) {
          NavigatorFunction.push(
            context,
            OtpScreen(
              phone: state.sendResponseModel.phone,
              isWhatsapp: state.isWhatsapp,
              hash: state.sendResponseModel.hash,
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state is AuthOtpFailed) {
          UtilityFunction.showScaffoldMessenger(    // function to show scaffoldmessage
              context, state.message, Colors.blue);
        }
      },
      child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomInputBox(mobileController),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            CustomButton(
              isWhatsapp: false,
              onTap: () {
                context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                    AuthOtpRequestEvent(mobileController.text, false));
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            CustomButton(
              isWhatsapp: true,
              onTap: () {
                context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                    AuthOtpRequestEvent(mobileController.text, true));
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

## OtpScreen.dart

```
class OtpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();
  final String phone;
  final String hash;
  final bool isWhatsapp;

  OtpScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.phone,
      required this.hash,
      required this.isWhatsapp});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthVerifySuccess) {
          NavigatorFunction.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, const NavigatorBar());
        }
        if (state is AuthVerifyFailed) {
          UtilityFunction.showScaffoldMessenger(
              context, state.message, Colors.blue);
          otpController.text = "";
        }
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 100),
          OtpInputField(   // Complete code below
            phone: phone,
            hash: hash,
            otpController: otpController,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          ResendOtpWidget(   // Complete code below
            phone: phone,
            isWhatsapp: isWhatsapp,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          CustomButton(
            onTap: () {
              context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                    AuthVerifyRequestEvent(
                      phone,
                      hash,
                      otpController.text,
                    ),
                  );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


//____________________________________________________________________________________________

class OtpInputField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController otpController;
  final String phone;
  final String hash;
  const OtpInputField(
      {required this.otpController,
      required this.phone,
      required this.hash,
      super.key});

  @override
  State<OtpInputField> createState() => _OtpInputFieldState();
}

class _OtpInputFieldState extends State<OtpInputField> with CodeAutoFill {
  final SmsAutoFill autoFill = SmsAutoFill();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: PinFieldAutoFill(
        onCodeChanged: (code) => {
          if (code != null && code.length == 4)
            {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
              context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthVerifyRequestEvent(
                  widget.phone, widget.hash, widget.otpController.text))
            }
        },
        onCodeSubmitted: (code) => {
          context
              .read<AuthBloc>()
              .add(AuthVerifyRequestEvent(widget.phone, widget.hash, code))
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        currentCode: widget.otpController.text,
        controller: widget.otpController,
        codeLength: 4,
        cursor: Cursor(
          width: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
          radius: const Radius.circular(1),
          enabled: true,
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listenForCode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.otpController.dispose();
    autoFill.unregisterListener();
    cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void codeUpdated() {
    widget.otpController.text = code!;
    listenForCode();
  }
}


//____________________________________________________________________________________________

class ResendOtpWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phone;
  final bool isWhatsapp;

  const ResendOtpWidget(
      {required this.phone, required this.isWhatsapp, super.key});

  @override
  State<ResendOtpWidget> createState() => _ResendOtpWidgetState();
}

class _ResendOtpWidgetState extends State<ResendOtpWidget> {
  late Timer _timer;
  int _resendTimer = 30;
  bool _isButtonActive = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(width: 64),
        BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is AuthOtpLoading) {
              return const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
                width: 15,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(strokeWidth: 2),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: _isButtonActive
                    ? () {
                        context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthOtpRequestEvent(
                            widget.phone, widget.isWhatsapp));
                      }
                    : null,
                child: Text(
                  _isButtonActive
                      ? 'Resend OTP'
                      : 'Resend OTP in $_resendTimer seconds',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: _isButtonActive
                        ? Colors.blue.shade900
                        : Colors.grey[600],
                    fontWeight:
                        _isButtonActive ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (mounted) {
        if (_resendTimer > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _resendTimer--;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _timer.cancel();
            _resendTimer = 30;
            _isButtonActive = true; // Reset the button state
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

## NavigatorBar.dart - Home.dart

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, UserDataState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state == SplashScreenState.authenticated) {
            return Text(state.user.fullname);
          } else {
            return Text("Unkown");
          }
        },
    );
  }
}
```

Just want to verify that I am doing good in tech :)

Open for the suggetion to increase security and performance. Feel free to comment or answer.